# Ubuntu Error: Already running on PID 14733

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow

Trying to run my apache airflow DAG on my local machine but when i execute command

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

i am getting this error

Error: Already running on PID 14733 (or pid file '/home/rahul/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid' is stale)

I already tried killing the given process id but still getting the error.

```
kill -9 14733
```

How can i fix this..?

Comment: `sudo kill -9 14733` should have done the trick

Comment: there was more than one process that was running and there wasn't any way to kill all of them at once with simply using kill and killall did that for me

Answer (score 2):

I tried killing all the process that starts with airflow and that did the trick

```
killall -9 airflow
```